# How to use the onclick event as a selector in webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Here is the element:

```
<label title="Place Order" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="AjaxPageLoad(fno, 'FNOOrder');">Place Order<div></div></label>
```

I am trying to click on this but need to use the `@onclick` as the main differentiator. I read the other similar questions but can't seem to get this to work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'fno')]").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'FNOOrder')]").click()
```

Error I get:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a id="lnkFNO" class="active" href="javascript:void(0)"> could not be scrolled into view
```

But the element is visible so I assume that the `xpath` must be wrong.

Comment: Shared piece of HTML is for `label` while code is for clicking anchor node. Can you share correct (more complete) HTML sample?

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the desired element using the `onclick` event you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the follwing solution:

- *xpath* using *onclick*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@onclick=\"AjaxPageLoad(fno, 'FNOOrder');\"]"))).click()
  ```
- *xpath* using *onclick* and *title*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@title='Place Order'][@onclick=\"AjaxPageLoad(fno, 'FNOOrder');\"]"))).click()
  ```
- *xpath* using *onclick*, *title* and *innerHTML*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@title='Place Order'][@onclick=\"AjaxPageLoad(fno, 'FNOOrder');\"][contains(.,'Place Order')]"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css selector, if you are familiar with web development, it should be easier.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label[onclick*=fno]").click()
```

Above code will select label with `onclick` argument contains 'fno' string. Here you can find all selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: What is the point of using CSS selector to locate node by `id` attribute? What's wrong with `driver.find_element_by_id("fno").click()`? Also it's unlikely that OP has access to modify HTML source or that OP interested in this kind of solution...